# How to use different content uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using `UITableView` with *group-type*, and I am adding different content on `UITableViewCell`
and each `indexPath.section` I am checking in `UITableViewCell` delegate method

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        cellIdentifier = (indexPath.row % 2 == 0 ? @"EvenCell" : @"OddCell");
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier]; 
        if (cell == nil) 
    {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                              reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
            if (indexPath.section == 0) 
            {
                 // adding image

                // called
            }
     else if (indexPath.section == 1) 
            {
               // adding lable
                called
            }
 else if (indexPath.section == 2) 
            {

                // adding panorma gps
                called
            }
 else if (indexPath.section == 3) 
            {
               not  called  // this section problem
            }
else if (indexPath.section == 4) 
            {
               not  called  // this section problem
            }
        }
return cell;
   }
```

I have given number of section 5, but it is calling only `indexPath.section` 0, 1, and 2 only.

Comment: how much rows and sections you got? Maybe you have only 2 sections.

Comment: post code of numberOfRowsInSection and numberOfSectionsInTableView methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that that you only have only two types of `cellIdentifier` values (i.e. two types of cells you're reusing), but you appear to have five different layouts. The problem is that layouts are only called if a reused cell was not found. Thus, by the time you get down to section 3, `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` is probably succeeding and reusing a cell that has scrolled off screen, and thus your code inside the `if (cell == nil)` block is not getting called at all for sections 3 and 4.

You can remedy that by either having more cell types, unique to the section number, too, e.g.:

```
NSString *cellType = (indexPath.row % 2 == 0 ? @"EvenCell" : @"OddCell");
NSString *cellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%d", cellType, indexPath.section];
```

You haven't shared what the even/odd logic is used for, so I'm not entirely sure what that's needed for. Assuming it's for something simple like `backgroundColor`, then I might be inclined to drop even/odd from the `cellIdentifier` altogether (and move the setting the background color outside the `if (cell==nil)` block), and just use the section number for the cell identifier:

```
NSString *cellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MyCellSection-%d", indexPath.section];
```

We'd need a better sense of how different the various cells are configured (what is the degree of commonality) to make concrete suggestions on the best way to format this. But the key issue is that your `cellIdentifier` choices have to correspond to what's inside the `if (cell == nil)` block.

Comment: i have  use  same approch , i have solved problem thanks

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are returning 5 from here

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 5;
}
```

Comment: same thing i am doing dude

Answer (score 0):

You call a method to the number of sections as follows?

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 5;
}
```

Try call your methods after `if(cell == nil)`:

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                  reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}
if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    // adding image

    // called
}
else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
    // adding lable
    called
}
else if (indexPath.section == 2) {

    // adding panorma gps
    called
}
else if (indexPath.section == 3) {
    not  called  // this section problem
}
else if (indexPath.section == 4) {
    not  called  // this section problem
}
```

Comment: This is fine, too, but if you move all of the "add image" outside of the `if (cell == nil)` block, you have to make sure you add code to remove it from the cell  (e.g. you hit section 3, and you don't know whether the cell was previously from section 0, 1, or 2).

Comment: i will add like that content on cell, but one problem will come , like it will add more time on cell , it means number  time of scroll